# Windows Fast Startup - How to determine when the last boot/reboot occured

Tags: c#, windows

Is there some method in .Net I can use to ascertain when a Windows PC was last Shutdown when "Fast Startup" has been enabled on the PC. If the end user selects Shutdown rather than Restart, then none of the solutions I have found so far on StackOverflow give me that information.

"Up Time" and "LastBootUpTime" are NOT updated when a "Fast Startup" enabled   Windows PC is put into Sleep mode or Shutdown.

In short - Is there some way to ascertain the last time the user "Shutdown" the computer?

Comment: Reboot = Shutdown + Boot, there is no reboot method at all, you may check the different between shutdown and boot time to detect a reboot event.

Comment: _"If the end user selects either Shutdown or Sleep rather than Restart, then none of the solutions I have found so far on StackOverflow won't give me that information"_ -- meaning what, exactly? Sleep isn't a boot, so naturally that user action won't affect the last-boot time. But shutdown certainly results in a boot, the next time the power is turned back on (i.e. the earliest you'd be able to check the time anyway). Please fix your question so that it shows what you tried, explains what that attempt did, and why that's not what you want.

Comment: @NatPongjardenlarp. I assume you are talking about "LastBootupTime". With "Fast Bootup" enabled, the "LastBootUpTime" is the last time the computer was RESTARTED. The value is NOT changed when you select Shutdown.

Comment: @shingo Correct but I still want to know when the computer was last booted up. To expand - when was the computer last Started.

Comment: @PeterDuniho When "Fast Startup" is enabled, Shutdown does NOT result in a boot. The computer goes into Hibernation.

Comment: @David: please edit your post to provide any necessary clarifications. The comments here are for other users to solicit improvements, not for you to provide those improvements. Also note (as others already have pointed out): the computer entering a hibernation state doesn't involve rebooting the OS, so the information you are getting now is accurate. If you want to instead track power state changes, that's different. Your question isn't clear about what you want to track or why, but the power API and/or WMI may get you what you want. Worst case, you could check the event log directly.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I have edited my question to make it more succinct. I have always used the term boot/reboot to mean start or restart a computer. That is - Hibernation and/or Sleep are not part of the boot/reboot process. ergo Hibernation and /or Sleep are not part of the Start/Restart process either. I'm still looking for an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the system event logs

To get all logs

```
foreach (var log in EventLog.GetEventLogs())
    if(log.Log == "System")
        foreach (EventLogEntry entry in log.Entries)
```

To get boot logs, filter the event ID with 6009 (mentioned by [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/159612/windows-server-last-reboot-time#159616))

```
(entry.InstanceId & 0x3FFFFFFF) == 6009
```

To get awake logs, filter the event ID with 1 and source with "Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter"

```
(entry.InstanceId & 0x3FFFFFFF) == 1 && entry.Source == "Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean you want to find when the computer was last booted when fast-startup is enabled?

1. Query event log from .NET. Haven't done this but looks like you use  System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader namespace [ from Googling :-)  ]
2. Look for event id 27 (Boot event) and check boot type:

0x0- cold boot from full shutdown
0x1- hybrid boot (fast startup)
0x2- resume from hibernation

i.e. if it was a boot from fast startup then you need to look for event id 27 + boot type 0x1